# Why some class cannot be jumped into for investigation in jd-gui for android app?

Tags: android, dex2jar, jd-gui

I want to investigate a apk and I have make it to `com.a.app_classes-dex2jar.jar`.
However, when I drag and drop it into `jd-gui.exe`, I find some lines of the obfuscated code cannot be jumped to and don't what the line actually done.

```
b b = new b();
f f = new f();
```

but then the `b` and `f` is not further used inside the method. I just want to know why I move my mouse on class `b` has no hyperlink for me to jump into detail of class `b`, and I have a quick look into the whole .class file and does not see any custom class `b` is written. What are the lines doing?